# Pulling send information via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Am I able to pull all the send information for all the emails I have recieved using soap API? I know I can do this using the system views but wanted to know if it's possble to do this via SOAP API? Any examples would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.  I would create a Data Extension to hold the relevant results of a query of the system views.  Then, create a query activity, to copy the data into the data extension.  Finally, I would create a data data extract activity to export the results to a CSV.  All of this I would do within the SFMC application, not via API.

I can call both the Query Activity and the Data Extract Activity with two SOAP calls.  Or you can put them in an automation within AutomationStudio,  and start that automation via API.

Good luck.